# C++ "delete" slow in debug build

Tags: c++, debugging, delete-operator

The software I'm working on is a plugin DLL, everything works fine and as expected during normal execution but when the host unloads the module, memory deallocation is slow (several arrays of objects are deallocated via "delete[]". If I take away all the "delete []" instructions, module unloading becomes much faster ). This happens just with the debug build, the release build unloads in no time. I've also noticed that if I place a breakpoint in one of the destructors debug is also slow (it takes an average of 2secs per instruction). Any ideas as to why this happens ?

Comment: In Visual Studio debug builds there is memory corruption detection in the allocation routines. These will take some time. There also is memory leak detection.

Comment: I find 2 seconds per instruction hard to believe.

Comment: @KeithRandall I bet "per instruction" only included the number of `delete[]` he found in the code.  I bet each of those was executed many times.  I also bet those call `delete` many more times, which he also didn't include.  I'd guess each heap deallocation was _much_ less than 2 seconds.

Comment: Before destroying the main object a "flush" method is called, the method other than freeing resources sets all the object variables to zero. when debugging it takes 2 seconds to execute each and every instruction in the method, not just the "delete" ones, even if it is something like "arrayptr=NULL"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your case. I have seen something similar with MS IDE and Debug builds and reporting memory leaks. If for some reason lot of objects did leak then reporting them into Output window took considerably lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to enable my psychic debugging hat and assume that you are using VC++. This is a crucial piece of information and since it isn't supplied I have to guess.

Next, you say "it takes an average of 2 secs per instruction". If by "instruction" you mean assembly language instruction then that is a separate problem of the debugger running slowly. There are various causes such as having too many breakpoints set (https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/xperf-and-visual-studio-the-case-of-the-breakpoint-hangs/), having Show Threads in Source set (https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/visual-studio-single-step-performance-fixes/), or other possible causes. But this is a *debugger* problem, not a debug build problem.

The Windows heap runs slower when running under a debugger - it does additional checks. That could be the problem but note that that is irrelevant to whether you are running a debug build.

The CRT heap runs slower in debug builds and acquires locks on every allocation and free, which serializes allocations. And, if _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF is set then the entire heap will be checked for consistency on every alloc and free, which can make them orders of magnitude slower.

The only way to know which is the real problem is to profile.